# An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Tags: java, automation, appium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8dvH.png)I am automating android application using Appium in Java application. I have succesfully automated the Login test case. but on home screen of my application appium is unable to find element using search strategies by Id or xpath

I want to click on the highlighted icon as shown in image. but clikable is false so i have written the tap method for it.but still its not clicking on it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide more details on your implementation, we need to see your search strategies and the layout of your login screen, so we can tell you where the problem is.

Comment: is this a hybrid app ?

Comment: @marc TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);
  WebElement EB = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Easyload/Bundles']");
  t.tap(tapOptions ().withElement(element (EB))).perform();

Comment: @amit Its Native android app